# How to remove a Yeoman generator

Tags: yeoman

I accidentally installed a generator that I don't want.
I can't find any method to remove it.
What should I do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Generators are just normal npm modules, so you can remove it with

`npm uninstall -g generator-[nameOfGenerator]`

Comment: How do you remove a generator with spaces in the name? I tried enclosing it in quotes, but it says it's not installed.

Comment: Looks like you can replace the spaces with hyphens. E.g. `npm uninstall -g generator-app-with-spaces`

Answer (score 6):

`npm uninstall -g [generator-name]` **might** not fix the UNMET DEPENDENCY.
If you won't mind to reinstall the affected modules:

1. cd to your npm directory (e.g. /usr/local/bin/node_modules)
2. `rm -rf [generator-name]`
3. `npm cache clean`
4. `npm install -g [generator-name]`

Answer (score 5):

Search for generators with

```
npm list -g --depth=0 | grep 'generator'
```

Remove generator with

```
npm uninstall -g [generator-name]
```

NOTE: Don't include '@[version] ' that follows the generator name

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add something for posterity:

If you get an number of errors of class 'peerDependencies' for yeoman's generators, updating yo alone will not cut it - you need to remove all generators that throw the error and then reinstall whatever module lead to the trouble.

Unfortunately, as far as I ahve chekced, regex is not supported by npm.