# npm ERR: peerinvalid The package generator-karma does not satisfy its siblings peerDependencies requirements

Tags: yeoman, bower

When I run

```
 npm install -g yo grunt-cli bower
```

at my terminal I get the following dependency error:

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package generator-karma does not satisfy its siblings'
peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer generator-angular@0.5.0 wants generator-karma@~0.5.0
npm ERR! System Darwin 12.4.1
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo" "grunt-cli" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/ryanwieghard/code/angin/indie-cinema-tools
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.20
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.11
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ryanwieghard/code/angin/indie-cinema-tools/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I am not sure how to resolve this. Is there a way to manually install  `generator-karma@~0.5.0` ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The new version of yeoman installs bower and grunt for you (so you don't need those on your npm line anymore).  So, just to be safe remove what you have:

> npm remove -g yo bower grunt-cli

And then try this install

> npm install -g yo

Some people still experience the problem you're having though, here's the issue and in comments are a number of different things to try if the above doesn't resolve your issue:  https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/220

Comment: I've removed and reinstalled everything I can think of based on this thread, the one you've linked and many others. In cannot install generator-angular or generator-socketio OR generator-karma. Each reports this error that seems to always come back to generator-karma and I think it failing to install is the root of the issue but I don't have my brain wrapped around NPM enough to understand this any further.

Answer (score 11):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24084524/3692197

This helped me.

I uninstalled all the dependent generators which are throwing error

```
npm uninstall -g generator-[generator-name]
```

Update Yo

```
npm update -g yo
```

Install the required generator

```
npm install -g generator-[generator-name]
```

Comment: Yeah, I did the accepted answer and then this and finally got a result.

Answer (score 6):

This one helped me:

```
npm uninstall -g generator-karma && npm install -g generator-angular
```

Comment: Doesn't work any more - generator-karma seems to be installed again and cause the problem

Answer (score 3):

Before updating or re-installing `yo`, you must remove all generators (in my case generator-angular)

```
npm remove -g generator-angular
```

Then you can update yeoman

```
npm update -g yo
```

And smile :)

Answer (score 0):

I had to do "sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-karma"
then npm update -g yo